# Unknown .htaccess code

Tags: apache

Im in the process to launching a website which I rebuild with WordPress and came across this little bit of .htaccess code below.

The site was using a CMS which was build in the 1990! and in the .htaccess the following code was inside, can someone tell me what if does

```
RewriteRule ^.htaccess$ — [F]
```

Answer (score 1):

It causes a 403 Forbidden error if someone tries to access the .htaccess file.

See the Apache manual here for more info:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html

Answer (score 1):

This format keeps others out of your `.htaccess` file:

```
<Files .htaccess>
 order allow,deny
 deny from all
</Files>
```